# Getting the nth column of a dataframe using a for loop

Tags: r, loops, dataframe

Say I have this really simple dataframe called ***sample***:

```
read.table(header=TRUE,text="a_1 a_2 a_3
                              1    1   1
                              1    1   1
                              1    1   1")
```

I would like to take the nth column of this dataframe through the use of a for loop. For example:

```
for(i in i:3) {
    nth <- sample$a_[i]
    #there are still a lot more lines of code after this, think a bajillion calculations
}
```

Well obviously this won't work (I'm thinking Java really hard). Any equivalent for this in R?

This is a newbie question from a newbie R programmer.

Thanks to anyone who replies.

**EDIT**
This is only the simplest form of the situation in question. The true dataframe I have is incredibly wide.

Comment: thanks for the edit. I forgot the MVP rule here on StackOverflow.

Comment: you don't need a loop for that. If df is a data.frame. `df[,4]`. will get you the 4th column.  `df[3,]`, will get you the third row. I suggest that you take some time to get at `tutorial` in R. Will save you a lot of time. :-)

Comment: this is only the simplest situation I can muster. The actual dataframe is incredibly large. Also, there are some lines of code that I have to do after the use of the nth variable.

Comment: You probably need to start with something like this: `for(i in 1:3) { nth <- paste0('sample$a_',i) }`

Comment: On a side note: don't give your dataframe the same name as a function. It could mess up your code.

Comment: The paste0 function returns a string, if I'm doing this right. somewhere down the line a piece of code returns an error. Apparently, it need a numeric vector as an argument. Thoughts?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `data_frame[, "column_name"]` notation to access columns by name. For your example it will look like:

```
col_names <- colnames(sample)
for(i in c(1:3)) {
   nth <- sample[, col_names[i]]
   print(nth)
}
```

It gives

```
[1] 1 1 1
[1] 1 1 1
[1] 1 1 1
```

For more complicated cases you can use `eval` function to evaluate command from a string. Here you will probably need `sprintf` function to prepare that string. For example:

```
for(i in c(1:3)) {
    # prepare call string
    name_call <- sprintf("sample$a_%s", i)
    # evaluate command from string
    nth <- eval(parse(text = name_call))
    print(nth)
}
```

And again it gives:

```
[1] 1 1 1
[1] 1 1 1
[1] 1 1 1
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for (i in 1:n){nth=sample[,i]}
```

Would simply give you the nth row, after Looping through 1:n.

If you have a praticular string with rows you want to loop through, then you could create a vector

```
z<-c(1,3,6)

sample<-read.table(header=TRUE,text="a_1 a_2 a_3 a_4 a_5 a_6
                              1    1   1 2 3 4
                              1    1   1 5 6 7
                              1    1   1 8 9 10")
```

and just

```
for (i in 1:length(z)){nth=sample[,z[i]]}
```

If you don't want to overwrite the columns, then you can just take nth[i] and save a set of columns.

I hope that was the answer you were looking for.

Comment: It can be simpler than this, because z is a list, you can just use `i` directly: `for (i in z){nth=sample[,i]}`

Comment: Hi, so uhh its actually about columns, Apologies if the question title says "row", I have edited the question to reflect this mistake on my part.